# Assumptions of Logistic Regression Cathegorical predictors only

Tags: econometrics, r, logit

I have a logit model predicting the outcome 1 or 0.

My predictors are sociodemographics such as gender, income - intervals into categories like a: 1000-5000 usd, b:5000-15000 usd. etc, having a car, being student of high school - a, uni -b, elderly c.. ETC.

I have found several assuptions that need to be met for a logit model. My concern is  linearity of independent variables and log odds. I have found that the boxTidwell test is a way to go, but it only works for numerical variables.

I have also found that when u have only binary predictors you don´t need to check for this assumption. How it is when I have this cathegorical predictors such as income that is not continious? There is not any tests, do I have to check this assumption ?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to check the assumption of linearity when using categorical predictors, because the notion of linearity is not defined for them. We can define linearity such as $y=a+bx$ for a pair of numerical variables $(y,x$). However, the equation does not make sense if $x$ is not numerical. What would it mean to say the relationship is linear between a numerical vector $y$ denoting the yearly salary and a categorical vector $x$ denoting a person's name (Alex, Bob, Christopher, ...)? Or between the price of a car $y$ and the car's color $x$ (white, red, blue, ...)?